# Working with mixed datetime formats in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I read a file into a pandas dataframe with dates that vary in their format:

- either the American: `YYYY-MM-DD`
- or the European: `DD.MM.YYYY`

They come as a string. I would like to format them all as a date object so `pandas.Series.dt` can work with them and ideally have them in the second format (`DD.MM.YYYY`).

`pandas.Series.dt` gets confuesed with the two different spellings in one column.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with both formats separately, so get missing values if format not match, so for new column use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2000-01-12', '2015-01-23', '20.12.2015', '31.12.2009']}) 
print (df)
         date
0  2000-01-12
1  2015-01-23
2  20.12.2015
3  31.12.2009

date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce', format='%d.%m.%Y')
df['date'] = date1.fillna(date2)
print (df)
        date
0 2000-01-12
1 2015-01-23
2 2015-12-20
3 2009-12-31
```

> and ideally have them in the second format

Format of datetimes in python/pandas is by default `YYYY-MM-DD`, if need custom one it is possible, but values are converted to strings, so datetimelike functions failed:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
print (df)
         date
0  12.01.2000
1  23.01.2015
2  20.12.2015
3  31.12.2009

print (type(df.loc[0, 'date']))
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check which of the two format you have and apply `pandas.to_datetime` with that format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2000-01-12', '2015-01-23', '20.12.2015', 
'31.12.2009']}) 
print(df)
         date
0  2000-01-12
1  2015-01-23
2  20.12.2015
3  31.12.2009

def date_formator(date):

    if '-' in date:
        return pd.to_datetime(date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
    else:
        return pd.to_datetime(date, format = '%d.%m.%Y')

df.date.apply(date_formator)
0   2000-01-12
1   2015-01-23
2   2015-12-20
3   2009-12-31
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```