# How to clean Pandas data frame column which contains mix of both datetime and date?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in a Pandas data frame that has a date column but has datetime and date mixed in together as follows:

```
2020-05-20 00:00:00
2020-05-21 00:00:00
2020-05-22 
2020-05-23
```

Is there any way to convert everything to a date format as follows:

```
2020-05-20 
2020-05-21 
2020-05-22 
2020-05-23
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with mixed date time formats in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390709/working-with-mixed-date-time-formats-in-pandas)

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen No, the date format is the same across the entire column. Just that a few have time (00:00:00) attached to them
.The answer by **jezrael** seems to be working. Will validate and update.

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen that's not a relevant dupe target, it;s about multiple *datetime* formats (`YYYY-MM-DD` vs `DD.MM.YYYY`). But this one is about a single date format, except that it may/may not contain the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to strings and then to datetimes, last to dates:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str)).dt.date
```